# Radio lights are on

Tags: audio, lights, chrysler, sebring

I have a 2001 Chrysler Sebring and when I turn my car off the radio still glows with the time and CD that's playing, is that normal?

Comment: Is it an original, or an aftermarket?  Has it done that all the time you have owned it?  Has anyone been changing the wiring?  It is generally not normal, but it depends who wired it up.

Comment: It does this with the key removed? I believe most chryslers have the ACC key position to the left of the off position that will leave the radio on with the key still inserted. Do the dome lights work normally? or do they stay on when the key is removed?

Comment: All the lights work except the blinkers inside and out. But yes the key is removed it's just the radio light that's on I turned off my dome lights so I know it's not because I left anything on. But the radio isn't playing or anything

Answer (score 2):

If when you open the door and the radio shuts off, then this is perfectly normal. Most cars since the early '90 (maybe before that?) have what's called a Body Control Module (BCM - manufacturers may call it something else, but they all serve the same purpose). The BCM will keep some of the accessories on for a period of time after you shut the vehicle off. My Silverado keeps the radio on for about 15 minutes, as an example. When you open the vehicle door, this tells the BCM to shut things down. It is a convenience item for your vehicle. If this is how your vehicle is behaving, then there's no issue.

Comment: It's like that with the door and closed it goes off after a while but it does stay on a long time

Comment: @Courtney - This seems like perfectly normal behavior. You may check your Owner's Manual, as the "on time" can be adjusted in some models. You may also find that your electric windows, if so equipped, can be operated during the "key off, before you open the door" period.